# AngluarJS + RoR + jQuery - problems with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with jQuery in my angular + ror application. I want to make few things with javascript , like removing and adding classes, but the problem is that I am not doing this inside angular controller or sort, I wanted to do in in separate .js file. And here's the catch, jQuery is working not the way it should, example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        console.log("CLICKED");
    });
    console.log($("a"));
});
```

Above code is not working , and console is showing that there is no "a" tag in my document. Even though there is "a" tag.

But this code below works, and it's showing to the console whole body element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function() {
        console.log("CLICKED");
    });
    console.log($("body"));
});
```

I'm using jquery-rails gem, below you can see my application.js file. I'm using asset pipeline to require all angular files (except tests of course).

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular.min.js
//= require angular-resource.min.js
//= require angular-route.min.js
//= require ./angular/angular_app_declaration.js
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

I generate only standard view with Ruby on Rails which is application.html.erb, I use RoR as an API, rest of views are handled by angular routing, and yes "a" tag is added by angular by generating templateUrl.

How can I make jQuery work?

Comment: Step 1 - don't use jQuery in your AngularJS app.

Comment: I do not see any `a` tags in your document

Comment: your problem is the <a/> tag is not there when the document.ready runs. Try using angular directives. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your jQuery to reach your  tag, you should be using [Angular Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

in your `HTML` that is loaded by angular template. You can do something like this.

```
<a href="http://example.com" custom-directive >Link</a>
```

then in your Angular `app.js`, make the directive:

```
app.module('App', [])

...

.directive('customDirective', [function(){
    return {
        link : function(scope, elem, attr){
            elem.on('click', function(){ console.log(' CLICKED ! '); });
        },
        restrict : 'A'
    }

}])
```